# Segmentation fault on fread. help!

Tags: c++, c

```
typedef struct {

    unsigned char b1, b2;

} cont;

cont buf[1024];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

         FILE* fp;

         fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb")

         if(fp!=NULL)

             fread(buf, sizeof (cont), sizeof (buf), fp);

          //do something with buf
          return 0;

}
```

Hello there, I am facing a segmentation fault error when I try to run this program. It used to work fine all of the sudden the segm. fault error appeared. The fread function  call is generating the error. Please help me!

Comment: The programs do not just stop working like that. What did you change? New compiler version? Something else?

Comment: nothing, I am using netbeans IDE on windows platform and I am using  cygwin g++ compiler

Comment: third parameter should be number of elements in the buffer (which is 1024), not its size in bytes (which is sizeof(buf))

Answer (score 3):

You're using fread() wrong - arg#1 is the size of elements to read and arg#2 is the number of elements to read (which should be 1024 in your case).

As a result, what you do reads `sizeof (cont) * sizeof (buf)` bytes, and that overflows your buffer.

See:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html

for the function documentation.

To clarify, you want to read 1024 elements but `sizeof(buf)` is 2048 (at least, maybe more if the struct is padded by the ABI of your platform).

Examples (coded so that they don't rely on a specific number of elements):

```
fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fp);    // fills the buffer (assuming it's buf[...])
fread(buf, sizeof(*buf), sizeof(buf)/sizeof(*buf), fp);    // ditto
```

I.e. if you want to pass the total size of the destination buffer, via `sizeof()`, then the other argument must be one, while if you want to pass the size of the data structure, then the other argument is the number of these that fits into the buffer.

Comment: @FrankH, why should he only be reading one? "buf" is big enough to take 1024 elements of type "cont" and sizeof(buf) should return 1024, so it should be ok.

Comment: The call looks fine to me. The first argument of fread() is the destination buffer.

Comment: Someone for strange reasons downvoted this answer that is the correct one. Apparently the OP doesn't understand that sizeof returns the size in chars, not the number of elements...

Comment: oh yeah the arguments were supposed to be like              fread(buf, sizeof (buf), sizeof (cont), fp); but I still have the same problem

Comment: Sorry my net interface is too slow to real-time react to comments :( updated this, as said, the total number of bytes fread() will put in to the destination buffer is arg#1 * arg#2. So if you want to pass a buffer size either of them has to be one, while if you want to pass a number of elements the respective other has to be the size of one element.

Comment: @AlastairG FrankH is corrent: sizeof(buf) is the grand total, namely sizeof(cont) * 1024

Comment: Ah, I understand what he was saying now. Maybe it's because it's Monday that I thought that for `typedef a buf[b]` doing sizeof(buf) would return "b" and not "a*b". However I'm sure I've seen people use that sort of thing with integer arrays and so on. E.g. `int array[10]; int i; for(i=0; i < sizeof(array); i++);` in example code.

Comment: @user532053 it's not just the order, the number is wrong. You need to specify the number of elements. `sizeof(buf)` is not the number of elements; it's the number of bytes used.

Comment: but this is how www.cplusplus.com defines it                                                                ptr
    Pointer to a block of memory with a minimum size of (size*count) bytes.                                                                                                     
size
    Size in bytes of each element to be read.
                                                                    count
    Number of elements, each one with a size of size bytes.
stream
    Pointer to a FILE object that specifies an input stream.

Comment: @Alastair: probably what you saw is `for (int i=0; i<sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); i++) ...`

Comment: @user532053 That reference page tells you exact the same thing like we did here. the parameter size tells, how big a single element is. The parameter count tells how many elements to read (of which each will be of course of the size specified). So the total number of bytes read will be size*count.

Answer (score 0):

Always check return values. How else do you know if you actually managed to read anything?

I think this may be because of padding. The "cont" type is defined as 2 bytes big, but will probably be padded to 4. However this should not cause a problem because even if sizeof(cont) returns 2 or 4, "buf" must be using the padded size and so still be big enough.

Comment: typedef struct {

unsigned char b1, b2;

} cont;

cont buf[1024];

Comment: Yeah I saw that after I posted. Your formatting was a bit broken - answer edited. Give me a few secs.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(buf) gives you the grand total of buf, not just the number of elements in it. Nevertheless, you should never every read directly into structs. Bad things await you, if you do it that way.

Also structs may be padded anywhere between their members, so you don't even know the exact memory layout of that struct you define.

To keep your program portable and safe always read files element by element and construct the data from that.

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < MAX_ELEMENTS && !feof(fil); ++i) {
    int c1, c2;
    c1 = fgetc(fil);
    c2 = fgetc(fil);

   if(c1 == EOF || c2 == EOF)
       break;

   buf[i].c1 = c1;
   buf[i].c2 = c2;
}
```

Does this look tedious and verbose? *Yes*, but that is for good reason. Always assume the contents of a file to be possibly corrupted. Just reading a file into memory assuming is **dangerous**!